# Monitor slack bot rtm api with new relic

Tags: node.js, websocket, newrelic, slack-api

We've built a Slack bot (written in Node) that connects to Slack's RTM API using [botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme.md). I believe that because the RTM API is WebSocket-based, I am unable to see any action on New Relic.

How can I configure New Relic to monitor my WebSocket calls that Botkit is making?

Comment: Hi @jamesdlivesinatree, have you found a way to do this? I'm also looking for an answer.

Comment: This is old as RTM is not recommended anymore.

Answer (score 0):

check the [New Relic docs on this](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/nodejs-custom-instrumentation#web-txn), or see an example below. Hope this helps~

```
var nr = require('newrelic')
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app)

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ping', nr.createWebTransaction('/websocket/ping', function (data) {
    socket.emit('pong')
    nr.endTransaction()
  }))
  socket.on('new-message', nr.createWebTransaction('/websocket/new-message', function (data) {
    addMessageToChat(data, function () {
      socket.emit('message-received')
      nr.endTransaction()
    })
  }))
})
```